# django views List to Detail search parameter

Tags: django, django-views

I have 2 models:

`Ovt` which is documents header data only (ovtnumber = mycommonfield)

`Ovr` which is all rows that refer to `Ovt` with field that isn't a pk ( refer only one `Ovt` by the mycommonfield).

I need to to access the list of rows in `Ovr` that refers to a selected `Ovt`, by mycommonfield.

views.py

```
class OvtListView(ListView):
    """ header """
    model = models.Ovt 


class OvtDetailView(DetailView):
    """  rows """ 
    model = models.Ovr
    # SELECT ••• FROM "ovr" WHERE "ovr"."id" = 1
```

What I need is for the SQL generated to be something like:

```
SELECT ••• FROM "ovr" WHERE "ovr"."mycommonfield" = 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't get exactly what you need. However from what I understood you want to get an object using the detail view.

`DetailView` always by default get one object based on the passed `PK` in the URL. Here is an example from Django docs.

If you have this URL pattern which will provide the details of an author

```
urlpatterns = [
    #...
    url(r'^authors/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', AuthorDetailView.as_view(), name='author-detail'),
]
```

Then your detail view will be something like this.

```
class PublisherDetail(DetailView):
    model = Publisher
```

If you want to add extra context you can use the method [get_context_data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#adding-extra-context)

---

> I need to to access the list of rows in Ovr that refers to a selected
>   Ovt, by mycommonfield.

From this I understood that you want to pass to your template the list of OVRs that are linked to your OVT which was selected in the detail view

This can be done also using `get_context_data`

```
class OvtDetailView(DetailView):
    """  rows """ 
    model = models.Ovt

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # get the list of OVRs and add it to the context

        context = super(OvtDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['ovrs'] = models.Ovr.objects.filter(mycommonfield=self.object.pk)
        return context
```